# jQuery set css value for a div depending on the position of another div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div on my page called '.nav-wrapper' - the positino of this div will be in one of multiple places depending on the user settings in the backend. What I am trying to do is using jQuery, determine the top position of this div and if it is a certain value, add a margin-top value to a different div.

For example, below I am trying to say if .nav-wrapper top position is 0, change min-height of .header-wrapper-other to 50px. Here is my code, however at the minute it does nothing:

```
var MenuPosition = $('.nav_wrapper').css('top').val();
if (MenuPosition == 0) {
    $('.header-wrapper-other').css('min-height','50px');
};
```

Here is the css for both divs in the example:

```
.header-wrapper-other {
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
min-height: 200px;
}

.nav-wrapper {
padding: 10px 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: please share your html code also. It is better if you can share jsfiddle link with your problem statement.

Comment: So what does `$('.nav_wrapper').css('top').val()` return? And what type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be `.css('top')` not `.css('top').val()`

but this will return a string like `XXpx` which is probably not what you want.

You should use the following to return a useable number for your comparison

```
var MenuPosition = $('.nav_wrapper').position();
if (MenuPosition.top == 0) {
    $('.header-wrapper-other').css('min-height','50px');
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mh5wb6Lz/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Make it like this,

change your class from **.nav_wrapper** to **.nav-wrapper** because in the css you are styling .nav-wrapper and in the jQuery you are referring it as .nav_wrapper :)

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/u6Lrnpgj/

```
var MenuPosition = $('.nav-wrapper').css('top');

if (parseInt(MenuPosition) == 0) {
    $('.header-wrapper-other').css('min-height','50px');
}
```

You don't need val(); it is to get values from input fields :)

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is only meant for `input`s and `textarea`

What you will need is `parseInt()` to make `MenuPosition` an integer.

```
var MenuPosition = parseInt($('.nav_wrapper').css('top'));
```